# Nesting NavigationControllers

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, nested

I have a fairly straight-forward navigation based app. It is like a "wizard" in that the user selects a series of prefs is a logically sequential way (that is, the subsequent options are determined by the previous choices).

Do this (a) -> then this (b) -> then this(c) then this (d).

Ah, but now I want to have a simple 2-stage navigationController that just functions in stage (b).
To be specific, viewController 1 is a table of 'favorites' and viewController 2 is a table of many possible choices.

So, I need to nest a navigationController for stage (b) within the bigger, overarching navigationController.

Just can't quite get my brain around this one. I'm an IB fan, but willing to do it programmatically if needed.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested...

I came up with this elegant solution.

I push a 'managing' viewController(1) onto the main navigationController(1), and then in that viewController(1) I add another navigationController(2) / assign the real root viewController(2) / then set the navigationController(2) view to the managingVC(1) view. Viola!

A few delegates later and I have a very slick app with nested navigation.

Comment: AddenDUM: (with the accent on dumb). When all was said and done, there was no logical reason to even do it this way. I was able to branch away from my main navController, and then pop back just fine. Sorry I wasted anyone's time.